# User.findOne() numa coleção que não é a 'Users'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Eu escrevi um app que tem uma lógica de verificação de email e é disparada quando o usuário faz o cadastro. Estou usando dois modelos no Mongoose: um para os usuários e outro para o token de autenticação. No modelo do token eu armazeno o userID:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu UserController, quando o app precisa autenticar o token que foi mandado para o email do usuario, ele o faz procurando na coleção Token. Depois de achar o token, ele precisa buscar o userId que está no modelo, de acordo com a imagem cima. Para isso eu tenho uma função User.findOne().

Eu gostaria de capturar o _userId:ObjectId("numberos-numeros") que está no registro, mas eu gostaria de chama-lo dentro da função, mais ou menos assim:

```
User.findOne({ _userID: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId._userID, ref: 'Token' })
```

Minha pergunta: tem um jeito de fazer isso, identificar o usário na coleção de usuário usando uma chave que está em outro coleção?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

A resposta é mais simples que eu imaginava:

```
async confirmationPost (req, res) {
    const token_ = req.body.token;
    await Token.findOne({ token:token_ }, function (err, tokenData) {
       if (!tokenData) {
          return res.status(),
       }
       else 
       {     
       tokenUser = tokenData._userId
       User.findOne({ _id: tokenUser }, function (err, user) {
       // logic-logic
       }
```

:-)

Eu podia capturar todo o conteúdo das informações do token, então foi só setar uma variável que ia na resposta do servidor e pegava o _userID.